# How do I connect a specific path on an AWS API Gateway to a specific ECS instance via Terraform?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm running an application in AWS ECS successfully behind a network load balancer, and able to access it via the internet. I'm trying to put it behind an API Gateway (with the eventual goal of making the VPC private so services can ONLY be accessed via the API Gateway). The thing I'm having trouble with is the best way to specify the service in the aws_api_gateway_integration configuration.

I can access the service successfully via the NLB. I've tried putting the URI into the aws_api_gateway_integration but it doesn't work for access, and probably isn't the best way to specify it since the DNS name will change. I'm unable to find any examples of API Gateway with ECS.

ECS Service Definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "cocktail-service-service" {
  name            = "${var.prefix}-cocktail-service-service"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.ecs-cluster.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.cocktail-service.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.cocktail-service.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.cocktail-service.revision}")}"
  desired_count   = 1

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.ecs-public-sg.id}"]
    subnets = ["${aws_subnet.dev-vpc-subnet-1.id}", "${aws_subnet.dev-vpc-subnet-2.id}"]  
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn  = "${aws_lb_target_group.ecs-target-group.arn}"
    container_port    = 8080
    container_name    = "cocktail-service"
    }
}
```

API Gateway definitions:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "cocktail-service-resource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev-api-gateway.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev-api-gateway.root_resource_id}"
  # path_part appears to be how to trigger catching the request
  path_part   = "cocktails"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "cocktail-service-method" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev-api-gateway.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.cocktail-service-resource.id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "cocktail-service-integration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.dev-api-gateway.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.cocktail-service-resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.cocktail-service-method.http_method}"

  type                    = "HTTP"
  uri                     = "http://load-balancer-name-goes-here.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cocktails"
  integration_http_method = "GET"

  # TODO: change connection_type to VPC_LINK once the VPC is private
  connection_type = "INTERNET"
  #connection_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_vpc_link.test.id}"
}
```

When I try to test this through the API Gateway console Test tool, I get a 500 internal server error.